# Spring AOP - inheriting NDC from parent thread - java

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, ndc

I am using Spring AOP and trying to intercept the different methods that are being called for a particular user operation. I am using NDC(nested diagnostic context) for this purpose. It is a multi-threaded environment, so I need to pass the NDC context from one thread to another in the @Before method of Spring AOP.

The **NDC.cloneStack()** and **NDC.inherit()** methods can be used in case I was making changes to the original program. But I am trying to do this from the **@Before** method which is called before each method of the program.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: That will not work. The `@Before` method is already executed with the new thread and as such the NDC isn't available anymore. You would need to copy the information before you start a new thread or schedule the task.

Comment: Even I am facing same issue. It would be very helpful if you can suggest a work-around @M.Deinum.